# New to ML and NLP. Is topic/subject extraction a good place to start?

Tags: nlp

I'm new to AI and specifically NLP, I always love to study things as part of a random project I decide to build, right now I'm working on a chat bot and I was looking for an easy way(in terms of code) to extract the main topic/subject from a sentence(in English), the problem is that wherever I search, even if it's a simple code, it combines a full sentence "meaning"(device parts of speech), I don't like to implement something I don't understand so a small step for how to extract only the subject will be really good and can help my bot with some directions, Is there a simple code(don't care what language it written with) to extract, only main topic/s from a sentence(in English)?.

Comment: I think you are looking for a [topic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) or a [summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization). These are fairly advanced models, though; I would recommend beginning with something simpler.

Comment: @Emre As I mentioned I'm new to the field, can you suggest any simpler ones?

Comment: Totally agree with @Emre. I would also check out Introduction to Statistical Learning. The authors have a MOOC too. https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesandScience/StatLearning/Winter2015/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could learn about [word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding). These will provide you a natural path to topic models, and many other NLP tasks. Look up [word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec).

I think it is better not to learn two new subjects (NLP and ML) at once. I would start with ML on its own; take [this class](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) perhaps. A good place to start is [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), or [binary classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification).

Comment: Thank you for the direction, I was really needed some guidance.